# ForEach thymeleaf javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use thymeleaf inside javascript.
my code work fine when i use th:each  with html

```
<table>
  <tr th:each="theme : ${les_themes_1}">
    <td th:text="${theme.id}">id</td>   
  </tr>
  </table>
```

but when i use forEach inside a script,it return me  null

```
<script   th:inline="javascript" >

/*<![CDATA[*/
 /*[# th:each="theme : ${les_themes_1}"]*/
        document.write(/*[[${theme}]]*/); //return null
        document.write(/*[[${theme.id}]]*/); //not working
   /*[/]*/
/*]]>*/

</script>
```

help plz !  thank you!

Comment: Your example works for me in thymeleaf 3...

Comment: I use thymeleaf 2.1.3 version! i'll try to change version

Comment: with thymeleaf 3 work fine, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of question has a pretty long history, going all the way back to the early days of the JSP spec. One key thing to remember about JavaScript is that it ***executes within your browser based on the output generated from your server-side Java components***. This is true for JSP and Javascript, Velocity and Javascript, JSTL and other custom tags and Javascript, as well as Thymeleaf and Javascript.  In this scenario, the Thymeleaf template is executed well before the Javascript.

Knowing this, one critical troubleshooting strategy is to simply view and inspect the HTML & Javascript source code you generate at runtime.